# Sub-subdomain Domain name for different environment

Tags: dns

If we have two components in a API

`api` `front-end`

and we have three environments `staging` `qa` `development`

and a domain name `superproduct.com`

What would be the most logical domain spacing:

```
http://development.front-end.superproduct.com
http://development.api.superproduct.com

http://qa.front-end.superproduct.com
http://qa.api.superproduct.com

http://staging.front-end.superproduct.com
http://staging.api.superproduct.com
```

or the other way around:

```
http://front-end.development.superproduct.com
http://api.development.superproduct.com

http://front-end.qa.superproduct.com
http://api.qa.superproduct.com

http://front-end.staging.superproduct.com
http://api.staging.superproduct.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are completely correct. It can differ organisation by organisation. 
Also, once you start using one of the domain namespace type, you will gradually remember the format and no issues will come. However, I can see one issue here which is related to SSL.

If you go with any one of the above mentioned namespaces, you need to generate multiple SSL certificates such as `*.api.superproduct.com` and `*.front-end.superproduct.com`.

If you go with other namespace type then SSL certs will be required for `*.staging.superproduct.com`, `*.qa.superproduct.com` and `*.development.superproduct.com`.

To avoid this, I would suggest you to have the domains in either of the following formats.

1. `<component-name>-<env-name>.superproduct.com`

Examples are:
`api-qa.superproduct.com`, `api-staging.superproduct.com` etc.

2. `<env-name>-<component-name>.superproduct.com`

Examples are:
`qa-api.superproduct.com`, `staging-api.superproduct.com` etc.

In this case, only one SSL certificate for `*.superproduct.com` will be required.

You can go ahead with the best possible option as per your requirements and analysis.